# How can the Android 4.2 multiple user API be used remotely?

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-multiple-users

The new Android 4.2 offers a feature called multiple users where users can have separate accounts, settings, and data.

I was wondering if there is a way for this API to be used remotely. For example, can users be made remotely rather than from the settings menu?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For example, can users be made remotely rather than from the settings menu?

If by "remotely" you mean "through some API", there is nothing in the Android SDK for this, sorry. It's conceivable something might be added in the future in the device admin APIs, but I would not count on it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Are you 100% sure about this? That's also my conclusion after some major research, but I just wanna be completely sure before I tell my boss it can't be done. Cheers.

Comment: @Rubylover: "Are you 100% sure about this?" -- if there were APIs for it, they would be listed at http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#MultipleUsers or would have shown up in the API differences report (http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/17/changes.html), and I have found no sign of any.